# Give different Color for Variable or Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors

I'm looking for addon or option in Visual Studio for C# to Color some Variables and Methods and Classes names.

for example:

```
int number = 1;
```

I want "number" be of different color. Not other variables but just this one. I'm kinda loosing visually track of all of my variables and Methods while they are all of black color, and I wish to give them different color or at list to those variables and methods that are of impotence to program for me to track and pay attention to.

Comment: It sounds like you need to structure your code better instead. Did you know that above the code pane in visual studio there is a drop down list to navigate between methods?

Comment: As I know that is not available with default visual studio package, you will need to get some view enhancing addons for that.

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking a look at this,definitely navigation list helps as hell. So far the closes thing I have found to my desired answer is to go to tools>Options>Environment>Fonts & Colors>Display Items: Identifier. Changes color of all Identifiers such as Variable, Method, Class etc. In addition - is there a away to see all variables like you can do with methods?

Comment: Not quite... you can right click it and find all references though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to colour individual variables but the following tips may help in making your code easier to navigate.

Further to my comment, if your mouse cursor was focused on the code pane of your project, you will see a drop down list as so that contains all the methods contained in the current class.

[image: Example Image]

Another good way to navigate through your code is the "Go to definition" option. Simply right click on a method within your code and there will be this option available, this will then take you to where the method is situated. In the image below you can also see different nagiation tools.[image: GoToDefinition]

Your other option is to split your code into regions

```
#region RegionName
  private Bitmap CreateBitmap(int width, int height, string s)
  {
  }
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
  }
#endregion
```

You could then collapse areas of your code as and when they are required

Comment: thank you very much for such detail explanation - it helps with navigation a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question if there is an addon and I have found one such - Telerik JustCode. You have to buy it but it does the job coloring Fields, Method, Property Identifiers and so on, making things very easy to catch with eyes and define what they are on the fly.

Comment: Interesting program. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Also Visual Assist X seems to do the needed job in quite a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Some times ago i used http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2?SRC=VSIDE. You can change the background color of methods with the plugIn.
I do not know a plugIn which can colorize variables.